# Cannot get value from summernote ,when using ajax update

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, summernote

when i click edit button (i used modal bootstrap) all value exist except textarea with summernote.

if you input something(in summernote) and cancel it ,your value doesn't disappear ... it should be clear .

forgive me, my english so bad .

here is my modal form :

```
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" ><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Formulir Berita</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body form">
                <form action="#" id="form" class="form-horizontal">
                    <input type="hidden" value="" name="id_berita"/> 
                    <div class="form-body">
                     <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-2">Tanggal penulisan</label>
                      <div class="col-md-9">
                     <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                </span>
     <input name="tgl" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" class="form-control datepicker" type="text">
                                    <span class="help-block"></span>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-md-2">Judul</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
 <input name="judul" placeholder="Judul" class="form-control" type="text">
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-md-2">Penulis</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
 <input name="penulis" placeholder="Penulis" class="form-control" type="text">
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
<div class="form-group" id="photo-preview">
               <label class="control-label col-md-2">Gambar</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                (Tidak ada gambar)

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-md-2" id="label-photo">Unggah Foto </label>

  <div class="col-md-7">
                                                    <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
                                                        <div class="input-append">
                                                            <div class="uneditable-input">
                                                                <i class="fa fa-file fileupload-exists"></i>
                                                                <span class="fileupload-preview"></span>
                                                            </div>
                  <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">                                                                
                  <span class="fileupload-exists">Ganti Foto</span>

                  <span class="fileupload-new">Pilih File</span>
                                                                <input name="gambar" type="file" />
                                                        </span>
             <span class="help-block"></span>
                                                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
                                                        </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-md-2">Isi</label>
 <div class="col-md-9">
<textarea name="isi" class="form-control" id="summernote" >
                            </textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Simpan</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Batal</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i 've been trying some code :

```
$('#summernote').summernote('code');
$('#summernote').summernote('reset');// and for resetting modal while Add Data
```

it doesn't  happen anything

my ajax function :

```
function edit_berita(id)
{
   save_method = 'update';
    $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // clear error class
    $('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string

    //Ajax Load data from ajax
    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('sistem/berita/ajax_edit/')?>/" + id,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data){
            // $('#summernote').summernote('code');
            $('[name="id_berita"]').val(data.id_berita);
            $('[name="tgl"]').datepicker('update',data.tgl);
            $('[name="judul"]').val(data.judul);
            $('[name="isi"]').val(data.isi);
            $('[name="penulis"]').val(data.penulis);

 $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
            $('.modal-title').text('Edit data'); // Set title to Bootstrap modal title

            $('#photo-preview').show(); // show photo preview modal

            if(data.gambar)
            {
                $('#label-photo').text(''); // label photo upload
$('#photo-preview div').html('<img src="'+base_url+'upload/berita/'+data.gambar+'" class="img-responsive" >'); // show photo
                $('#photo-preview div').append('<input type="checkbox" name="remove_photo" value="'+data.gambar+'"/> Remove photo when saving'); // remove photo

            }
            else
            {
                $('#label-photo').text(''); // label photo upload
                $('#photo-preview div').text('(Tidak ada gambar)');
            }         
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error get data from ajax');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify the summernote line like this :

```
$('#summernote').summernote('code', data.isi);
```

And to clear the content :

```
$('#summernote').summernote('code', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Text Area doesnot have value. jQuery .html() works in this case

```
$("textarea#summernote").html(data.isi);
```

Comment: i 've been trying to put your code in my edit function: and it doesn't  work
thank for your answer ..

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$("textarea#summernote").val(data.isi);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( '[name="isi"]' ).val(data.isi);
$( '[name="isi"]' ).summernote();
```